# How to retrieve Excel worksheet accidentally stored in SaveAsAdobrePDF.xlam

Tags: excel, vba, macos, adobe

**Setup**:
MS Excel for Mac 16.64
MacBook Pro
Mac OS Monterey (12.6)

Workbook contains 3 worksheets: A, B, C
Data from A and B are referenced in C like =A!F60 or =B!F60

**Error**:
While reordering the sheets, I grabbed sheet A using the tab and my finger slipped off the mouse. The worksheet tab was, as near as I can tell, completely off the bottom of the Excel window (basically, over the desktop) when I let go. I assumed that I had trashed the sheet, but not so.

**Problem**:
Data in C are still accurate. References now show up like =[SaveAsAdobePDF.xlam]A!F60
Once I figured out what .xlam was, I went looking to crack it open and get my sheet back.

- I am able to "open" the .xlam to get to the VBA script
- I can see the VBAProject (SaveAsAdobePDF.xlam) in the Project Window
- When I've tried to open that project, I get a password window. Of course I have no pwd for that!
- Excel is now giving me trouble with the VBA--hanging and I have to Force Quit.

**Questions**:

- Data are accurate in the combined worksheet C, but how can I get my sheet A back?
- Is there a logical reason why "dropping" the sheet would cause this Add-In to run?
- Is this .xlam from Adobe? I normally use Save As ... PDF if I need that result, so I'm not sure why I would have installed that Add-In.

Thanks!